# PureRenderMixin breaking with bound event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to optimize as much as I can my React components by using the PureRenderMixin and making sure all the props that are being passed are immutable and don't change from render to render.

One issue I'm running into is the case of mutating bound event handlers passed as props. More specifically, say I have a  that renders and array of  children:

In Parent:

```
onChange: function(key, data) {
    ...
},

render: function() {
        return this.state.array.map(function(object, index) {
            return <Child key={object.key} onChange={this.onChange.bind(key)} stuff={object.stuff}/>
        }
    }) 
}
```

In Child:

```
...
mixins: [PureRenderMixin]
...
```

It turns out that the PureRenderMixin always triggers an update inside the Child because its onChange prop is always a new instance (even though it's always bound to the same key). That is, each call to `anyFunction.bind(123)` generates a new value (ie. they are not ===).

How do people deal with this? Here's two ways I can think of:

1. Pass the unbound onChange handler, pass the key separately, and have the child call the onChange with the key itself -- this is a bit messy as it adds unecessary complexity to the child.
2. Cache the bound onChange handlers in the parent -- adds complexity to the parent (store them in a map? and for each handler?)
3. Have the PureRenderMixin skip the `on*` props -- this breaks when those handlers do change and are passed further down the hierarchy in the child.

I can't seem to find an elegant solution to this. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also memoize result of `bind`:

```
function memoizedBind(fn, context) {
  var cache = fn.__memoize_cache;

  if (!cache) {
    cache = fn.__memoize_cache = {};
  }

  var key = getKey(context); // if context is primitive can be just `context`

  var cachedFn = cache[key];

  if (!cachedFn) {
    cachedFn = cache[key] = fn.bind(context);
  }

  return cachedFn;
}
```

Then use `memoizedBind` instead of `bind`. It will return the same result of same function and context.

Answer (score 0):

I think #2 is the appropriate answer.  I don't think it is adding complexity, Child already has the key, so why not just have him pass it along.

```
Child = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(newData) {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.key, newData); 
  },

  render: function(){
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you meant #1. In react 0.13 you actually can't use this.props.key ... You need to pass the key as another separate prop. I mean it will work, but it's just something the child needs to remember for each of its handler.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking of key as an id, not the component key.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate component whose sole purpose is to partially apply arguments to the `onChange` handler method.

```
const PartialApply = React.createClass({
  _handler(...args) {
    this.props.handler.apply(null, this.props.partialArgs.concat(args));
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return (
      shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) &&
      shallowEqual(this.props.partialArgs, nextProps.partialArgs)
    );
  },

  render() {
    return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {
      [this.props.handlerName]: this._handler,
    });
  },
});
```

Then, to use it:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.array.map(object => {
        return (
          <PartialApply
            key={object.key}
            handler={this._handleChange}
            handlerName="onChange"
            partialArgs={[object.key]}
          >
            <Child />
          </PartialApply>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok, so use an intermediate component as a cache for the unbound handler + key of the child. This is a neat idea and it's re-usable. So far seems like the best solution (although I wish there was something simpler).
The very best way would be to be able to overload the === for bound function, although I image that is a more fundamental JS limitation.